# Broken libxml2 on Mac OSX 10.5.8

Tags: macos, system, osx-leopard, libxml2

While installing the latest version of libxml2 I managed to remove the system install of the library.

My install is under /opt and works fine, however of course many programs rely on the system version and now the programs (such as colloquy and calibre) crash on launch.

Is there a way to re-install the system version of the library without completely formatting the Mac?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing off, this was some time ago and in the end I cleaned everything up and formatted.